# High voltage self-oscillating boost

Tags: boost, flyback

When the boost from Vin=325V (high voltage) is designed there is a problem with starting of oscillation since high turns ratio between primary and excitation winding has to be used. How is usually deal with it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2X4fW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is the intended output voltage of the boost?  Is D1 really a 1N4007 - I suspect this would not be a suitable diode.   There are many control chips that can control a boost converter, I have not seen a self-oscillating boost converter implemented commercially for several decades.  Is this a school project, or just an academic exercise?

Comment: @FabioBarone Actually it is a flyback converter with one more secondary winding. I draw an example only. The converter decreases to about 10V. There is not much chip available in local stores. I am trying to build a spot welder.

Comment: For the community to help you, you do need to provide more details: input supply (voltage, type, is it from the AC grid?), output voltage and current, power, physical form-factor required (is it to be portable, how big, how heavy), cost target, etc

Comment: If you copied this from an existing design can you provide a link to the original?

Comment: Besides questioning D1, what is Q1? And does it *really* have hFE much greater than 100? At the required voltage rating, I highly doubt it. Compare turns ratio and R2 value, with R3 value.